# How to lowercase postgresql array?

Tags: postgresql

I need to lowercase array content in PostgreSQL, `lower(array['array_content']))` or `array[lower('array_content']))` does not work. Actual array is much, much longer.

`SELECT * FROM kliendi_aadress WHERE lower(linn) LIKE ANY (array['Tallinn', 'Tartu','Narva'])`

Can this even be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well ILIKE solved this problem for me

```
SELECT * FROM kliendi_aadress WHERE linn ILIKE ANY (array['Tallinn', 'Tartu','Narva']);
```

Answer (score 13):

the first that come to mind is ugly:

```
db=# select lower(array['Tallinn', 'Tartu','Narva']::text)::text[];
         lower
-----------------------
 {tallinn,tartu,narva}
(1 row)
```

Here I `lower` text representation of your array and then cast it back to array.

And so comparison:

```
db=# select 'tartu' = any (lower(array['Tallinn', 'Tartu','Narva']::text)::text[]);
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: I wonder the double casts will cause any potential performance issues? Assume if we already handled all the inputs correctly

Answer (score 2):

The `citext` extension can come in handy in this situation.

```
-- If you haven't enabled citext in your DB
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
select 'tartu' = any (array['Tallinn', 'Tartu','Narva']::citext[])
```

should work.