# How to LOWER elements in postgresql array in SELECT statement to do case insensitive search

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Can I lower the elements in an array column like I can a varchar or text column?

```
SELECT * FROM a_tbl a
WHERE LOWER(%(uw)s) = ANY (a.n_lst) -- how to lower?
OR LOWER(a.x) = LOWER(%(uw)s)
```

I saw in the documentation that I could use citext as my datatype. I might try to alter my table if there isn't a way to use LOWER

```
a_tbl
-----
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
n_lst TEXT[]
x VARCHAR(50)
```

Comment: Can you add more information like adding table data and your desired result.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like below:

```
select lower('Jonh') = any(lower(n_lst::text)::text[]) from a_tbl;
```

Comment: I had to lower the output of `regexp_matches` and this worked. I had to wrap it in a CTE since I needed to use it in `WHERE` with array overlap. Two hacks for a simple ask.

Answer (score 0):

[How to lowercase postgresql array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589501/how-to-lowercase-postgresql-array#answer-51589781)

```
SELECT * FROM a_tbl a
WHERE LOWER(%(uw)s) ILIKE ANY (a.n_lst) -- how to lower?
OR LOWER(a.x) = LOWER(%(uw)s)
```